# How do I retrieve a list of primary users of computers

Tags: list, powershell, wmi, sccm, import-csv

**How do I pipe the objects of a CSV file into the DeviceName parameter of Get-CMUserDeviceAffinity?**

I have a list of computers. I'd like to generate a list of the primary users for each of the computers in this list. I'm using powershell and the SCCM module and so far I've tried a one-liner as well as something more wordy to no avail.

***One-Liner fail*:**

```
Import-CSV C:\temp\computerlist.csv |  Get-CMUserDeviceAffinity -DeviceName $($_.Name)
```

***Script fail:***

```
$Computers = C:\computers.CSV
   ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
       Get-CMUserDeviceAffinity -DeviceName $_.Name
```

***Results of both fails:***

```
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'DeviceName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide
an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:77
+ ... p\computerlist.csv |  Get-CMUserDeviceAffinity -DeviceName $($_.Name)
+                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-CMUserDeviceAffinity], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.Cmdlets.Collections.C
   ommands.GetUserDeviceAffinityCommand
```

Comment: `Import-CSV C:\temp\computerlist.csv | ForEach-Object { Get-CMUserDeviceAffinity -DeviceName $_.Name }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the *automatic pipeline* varaible `$_` whereas you don't have a pipeline object in your foreach loop. Just use `$Computer` instead:

```
$Computers = C:\computers.CSV
   ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
       Get-CMUserDeviceAffinity -DeviceName $Computer.Name
}
```

Comment: At least it should be `$Computers = Import-Csv 'C:\computers.CSV'`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your csv is like this
[image]

You can try to use below PowerShell script:

```
$Computers = Import-Csv C:\computerlist.CSV
   ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
      $Name = (Get-CMUserDeviceAffinity -DeviceName $Computer.Name).uniqueusername
      write-host "$($computer.name) ------> $($Name) "
}
```

The Output:
[image]